# How to solve "uninitialized local variable" error message in Visual Studio with C++

Tags: c++

I am a student studying C++.

I tried to use a class pointer variable, but I always face error C4700 on line 17, even when I initialize the variable.

I think there is a problem with the class pointer that I wrote. Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class man {
public:
    char name[10];
    int age;
    double weight;
};

int main(void) {
    man* gildong;
    man* sunhee;
    man* comso;

    gildong->age = 20;
    sunhee->weight = 52.5; 
    comso->age = 25;

    cout << gildong->age << sunhee->weight << comso->age << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers there at all??

Comment: What's C4700? You need to include the actual error in the question.

Comment: You're also using uninitialized pointers, which is UB.

Comment: i just want to practice with class pointer variable.
i knew that there is no Error when i don't use the pointer.
@πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: `man* gildong;` does not point to anything.

Comment: the C4700 error is "uninitialized local variable" @ChrisMM

Comment: @임진욱 yeah, that's what it is, uninitialized, and no memory allocated where it should point to.

Comment: At StackOverflow when asking a question about an error in VS you should always copy the exact text of the error message to the question from the Output tab of Visual Studio. Switch your language to english first then compile and copy the exact text of the error message from the Output Tab (not the errors list).

Comment: [Another compiler's view of the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/GzWTqEcsY), with extra diagnostics enabled. This way you can see what the compiler is warning about and what happens when you ignore the warning.

Comment: Oh, i am so sorry about that @drescherjm

Comment: Thank you to everyone!! I realized what the problem was.

Comment: Recommendation: Make sure so you don't trip over the same problem is a slightly different form later. In your own words, what was the problem?

Comment: *"on line 17"* -- It is good to identify where the error occurs. However, this is not a good way to do that. Save people the effort of counting lines by giving us the exact line. (Hint: you might get this by copying the full error message -- some compilers echo the problematic line as part of the error message.) *In addition,* it might not be a bad idea to also add the comment `// << Error on this line` at an appropriate place in your code block.

Comment: ***i am so sorry about that*** No problem. I just want to give you advice on how to create a good question for the Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

you need

```
man* gildong = new man();
gildong->age = 20;
```

then

```
delete gildong;
```

Or even better

```
#include <memory>
....
std::unique_ptr<man> gildong = std::make_unique<man>();
gildong->age = 20;
```

learn to use smart pointers from day 1

Comment: Or no pointers at all. Automatic allocation is probably  going to be just fine here.

Comment: @user4581301 OP says he wants to play with class pointers in a comment

Comment: What? We're expected to READ the questions?

Comment: @user4581301 - to be fair it was about comment #5 not in the original Q

Answer (score 2):

The warning is telling you about an uninitialized variable or in this case *variables*.

In `main` you have not initialized your pointers before trying to access members. This leads to undefined behavior. While unlikely, the dangerous possibility exists that this program would "work" as expected.

Had you declared objects as below, the memory for them would have been automatically allocated and the default constructor run.

```
    man gildong;
    man sunhee;
    man comso;
```

As it is, though, you have declared *pointers* to `man` objects, but provided nothing for them to point *to*. You might do that with:

```
    man *gildong = new man;
```

After doing that you could write `gildong->age = 20;` and that behavior would be defined. You would want to remember to `delete` those objects allocated with `new`.